# Java - synchronized DateFormat - jxls

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, jxls

I need to use `DateFormat` object in `jxls` beans. If in my class I write the following:

```
private synchronized DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Will it be thread-safe? In the same class I have a method:

```
public void doSomething() {
    Map<String,String> beans = new HashMap<String,String>();
    beans.put("df",df);
    XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();
    transformer.transformXLS("template.xls", beans, "result.xls");
}
```

That is called from multiple threads.

If `synchronized` field doesn't help in this situation, what can I do to provide thread-safe date formatting from `jxls` without creating new `DateFormat` object every time?

Comment: FYI, the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes that supplant the troublesome old date-time classes are thread-safe including the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't add `synchronized` to fields like that.

1. You could create one every time you call `doSomething`:

e.g.:

```
public void doSomething() {
    Map<String,String> beans = new HashMap<String,String>();
    beans.put("df", new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"));
    XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();
    transformer.transformXLS("template.xls", beans, "result.xls");
}
```

Since each calling thread will get its own instance of `SimpleDateFormat` this will be threadsafe (assuming the SimpleDateFormat doesn't live long and get passed to other threads when it is passed on to the xslt transformer).

2. Create a `ThreadLocal` to handle multiple threads:

e.g.:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> df =
    new ThreadLocal<Integer>() {
         @Override protected Integer initialValue() {
             return new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
     }
 };
 public void doSomething() {
    // ...
    beans.put("df", df.get());
    // ...
}
```

3. Another option is to change your code to use the jodatime [`DateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) instead.  The DateTimeFormat class is thread safe.

Comment: I've heard that creating DateFormat object is expensive. So I think in that situation it's better to use one object thread-safely. Especially if date format is the same any time method calls.

Comment: I added a couple of threadsafe alternatives to creating a new one each time.